# Express $\int^d_c \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{b^2\sinh^2 u -a}}du$ in terms of elliptic integral.

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I want to express $$\int^d_c \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{b^2\sinh^2 u -a}}du$$ (where $a,b,c,d$ are real constants) in terms of elliptic functions. I have tried to make the naive change of variable $b^2\sinh^2 u -a =1-k^2\sin^2\theta$ (where $k$ is to be determined in terms of $a,b,c,d$ so the integral simplifies), but its Jacobian factor seemingly introduces more complication that simplification. Does anybody have any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: would $u\mapsto ix$ do anything?

Comment: That would lead to an integral with the correct $\sin^2 x$ factor, but the result would be complex, and the integral is real (although i have said nothing about $c,d$, in the actual problem I'm interested in, they take particular values that gurante the integral is real).

Comment: first of all, it might be helpful to include more information about the problem so that we can help you better. Second of all, are you sure that the integral is expressible as an elliptic integral?

Comment: Sorry for obscuring things, I thought that maybe adding too much details would make things worse. The integral is expressible as an elliptic one, sure. It defines the action variable in an elliptic billiard. The limits are $c=\mathrm{asinh}(\sqrt{a}/b)$ and $d=\mathrm{asinh}(B/b)$, where $B$ is another constant.

Comment: @Grimolatto "But the result would be complex." Assuming that the integral exists in $\mathbb{R}$ with the appropriate conditions for $a,b,c,d$, you can freely make the substitution $u \mapsto ix$ and still get a real result. You don't have to worry about your final result being complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the indefinite integral in general:

$$I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2\sinh^2 u -a}} du$$

Let $s^2=\frac{a}{b^2}, t=\sinh u, du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$

$$I=\frac{1}b\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-s^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$

Let $t=\cot\theta$

$$I=-\frac{1}b\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta-s^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$

Let $k^2=1+s^2$ and use: $\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$. We have

$$I=-\frac{1}b\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$

So you get the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: Brilliant! I admire (and certainly envy) that ability in making the correct changes of variables.

Comment: Thank you, glad you like it :)